# Grouped count aggregation in R data.table

Tags: r, count, aggregate, data.table

table that contain dates, buy values and sell values. I'd like to count how many buys and sells per day and also total number of buys and sells. I'm finding this a little tricky to do in data.table.

```
   date   buy sell      
2011-01-01  1   0
2011-01-02  0   0
2011-01-03  0   2
2011-01-04  3   0
2011-01-05  0   0
2011-01-06  0   0
2011-01-01  0   0
2011-01-02  0   1
2011-01-03  4   0
2011-01-04  0   0
2011-01-05  0   0
2011-01-06  0   0
2011-01-01  0   0
2011-01-02  0   8
2011-01-03  2   0
2011-01-04  0   0
2011-01-05  0   0
2011-01-06  0   5
```

The above data.table can be created using the following code :

```
 DT = data.table(
          date=rep(as.Date('2011-01-01')+0:5,3) , 
          buy=c(1,0,0,3,0,0,0,0,4,0,0,0,0,0,2,0,0,0),
          sell=c(0,0,2,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,8,0,0,0,5));
```

What I want as a result is :

```
   date   total_buys   total_sells
2011-01-01    1            0
2011-01-02    0            2
                and so on
```

Furthermore I'd also like to know the total number of buys and sells:

```
 total_buys   total_sells
     4            4
```

I have tried :

```
 length(DT[sell > 0 | buy > 0])
 > 3
```

Which is a strange answer (would like to know why)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
## by date
DT[, list(total_buys = sum(buy > 0), total_sells = sum(sell > 0)), by = date]
##          date total_buys total_sells
## 1: 2011-01-01          1           0
## 2: 2011-01-02          0           2
## 3: 2011-01-03          2           1
## 4: 2011-01-04          1           0
## 5: 2011-01-05          0           0
## 6: 2011-01-06          0           1

DT[, list(total_buys = sum(buy > 0), total_sells = sum(sell > 0))]
##    total_buys total_sells
## 1:          4           4
```

Comment: Sum adds the buy values - I'm looking to count them. The total buys and total sells are literally 4 each.

Comment: Thanks Jake would you mind explaining how this works ? kudos for a very succinct method to do this.

Comment: @user1480926 Which part are you confused about? `buy > 0` and `sell > 0` returns a `logical` so the sum of that is just the count that is non-zero. Using `by` in `data.table` lets you easily group by some variable.

Answer (score 3):

An alternative to @Jake's answer is the typical `melt` + `dcast` routine, something like:

```
library(reshape2)
dtL <- melt(DT, id.vars = "date")
dcast.data.table(dtL, date ~ variable, value.var = "value", 
                 fun.aggregate = function(x) sum(x > 0))
#         date buy sell
# 1 2011-01-01   1    0
# 2 2011-01-02   0    2
# 3 2011-01-03   2    1
# 4 2011-01-04   1    0
# 5 2011-01-05   0    0
# 6 2011-01-06   0    1
```

Or, without melting, just:

```
DT[, lapply(.SD, function(x) sum(x > 0)), by = date]
```

To get your other table, try:

```
dtL[, list(count = sum(value > 0)), by = variable]
#    variable count
# 1:      buy     4
# 2:     sell     4
```

Or, without melting:

```
DT[, lapply(.SD, function(x) sum(x > 0)), .SDcols = c("buy", "sell")]
#    buy sell
# 1:   4    4
```

Comment: @user1480926, thought I would share it because it would turn out to be more convenient if you have many more columns than just 2.